# Querying Many to Many polymorphic relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've following tables:

- `contacts(id, name, email, phone_no)`,
- `events(id, title, start_date, end_date)`,
- `addresses(id, city, state, country, zip_code)`,
- `addressables(id, address_id, addressable_id, addressable_type)`

Here `addressables` have many to many polymorphic relation for `contacts` `events`. `addressables` could also hold other polymorphic model class.

**Addres Model**

```
public function addressable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Event/Contact Model**

```
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Address::class, 'addressable');
}
```

I wanted to fetch addresses along with their associated models. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to

- List addresses with associated models
- List addresses for specific model type
- List addresses group by model type

**UPDATED**

Expected Outcomes:

**addresses**

```
id   |    address   
1    |    New York, USA
2    |    California, USA
3    |    Nevada, USA
```

**contacts**

```
id   |    name   
1    |    Albert King
2    |    Michelle Johnson
3    |    Sujit Baniya
```

**events**

```
id   |    title   
1    |    Event 1
2    |    Event 2
3    |    Event 3
```

**addressables**

```
id   |    address_id    |    addressable_id    | addressable_type   
1    |    1             |    1                 | Contact
2    |    2             |    1                 | Event
3    |    3             |    2                 | Contact
```

**EXCEPTED RESULT for Address::with('addressables')**

```
Address - ID 1
----Details (New York, USA)
----Contact (Albert King)
Address - ID 2
----Details (California, USA)
----Event (Event 1)
Address - ID 3
----Details (Nevada, USA)
----Contact (Michelle Johnson)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel's Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) for many to many polymorphic relations,
you have to edit your address model and add methods for `events` and `contacts` like so:

```
//Get all the contacts that are assigned this address
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Contact', 'addressable');
}

//Get all the events that are assigned this address
public function events()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Event', 'addressable');
}
```

**To answer your question**

Then to get all **addresses for a contact**, you can use the `addresses` dynamic property like so:

```
$contact = App\Contact::find(1);

foreach ($contact->addresses as $address) {
    //
}
```

**And for events:**

```
$event = App\Events::find(1);

foreach ($event->addresses as $address) {
    //
}
```

**Lastly**, you can retrieve Address events, contacts like so:

```
$address = App\Address::find(1);

foreach ($address->events as $event) {
    //
}

foreach ($address->contacts as $contact) {
    //
}
```

Comment: How can same stuff be achievable without defining functions in `Address` model? What I wanted to achieve is get all addresses along with their addressables and some filters based on addressables

Comment: What if you want to filter addresses that match a specific contact or event? I've found whereHasMorph but it only seems to work on one-to-many, with my many-to-many relationship I'm getting call to undefined method addressable (mine is actually userable). Basically, I want to be able apply a user filter to a task query builder, or in the case of this example, apply a contact or event filter to an address query builder.